# Is it possible to only execute code in design environment (android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I would like to be able to have my homegrown ImageView derivative execute one set of code in the design environment only, so I can test it's working correctly, but to have it do other, more useful stuff when it's actually executing (whether in debug mode or official release).

Is there a way to do this? I know there is a way in .NET (Visual Studio) but I can't find it for Android (Eclipse).

I would envision something like:

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView {

@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if( _designMode)
        {
            // execute some test code
        }
        else
        {
            // execute official code
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found the answer on stackoverflow (... embarassing.. didn't find it the first time I searched though.) So I'll give it here as well.

`isInEditMode()` (method of View)